# Sharding MongoDb with Nginx

Tags: mongodb, nginx

I'm new in MongoDb and I need to deploy MongoDb in many servers, I listened about Nginx,
but in mongo tutorial nothing is said about it, Can I deploy MongoDb in Ubuntu 12.04 with Nginx? and which way is better in MongoDb tutorial or nginx? and maybe can you recommend me any resourses to read about this?

Comment: Nginx and MongoDB are two totally different things. You need to read up on what exactly Nginx is and what MongoDB sharding is.

Comment: To expand on Sammaye's comment: Nginx is an http server and reverse proxy, which you can use for your web applications. You do not want to try to proxy or expose your MongoDB deployment through Nginx (see also: [MongoDB Security Guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/). What sort of MongoDB deployment are you thinking of across multiple servers -- are these independent MongoDB instances or meant to work together as part of a [replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) or [sharded cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)?

Comment: If you want a repeatable deployment process across multiple servers, you probably want to look at configuration management tools (i.e. Chef or Puppet). Unfortunately your of question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow (which is for programming advice rather than deployment questions or recommendations on specific tools). If you have a more specific question on deployment I would suggest asking on ServerFault (but also read the site's [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) guide before posting.